# Select box calling another element’s click event jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a div on my page witch is hidden : AddSupplier, I have a button on my page witch must show the div if its not visible, but the same button saves some stuff if the div is visible. So all that is working but in this AddSupplier div there is a select box "ddSupplierTypes" and when the select box gets clicked the AddSupplierButton click event gets triggered why is this, and is there a work around?

Tanks for any help.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>  
<html> 
     <head runat="server"> 
     <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
     <script type="text/javascript"> 

     $().ready(function() { 
         $('#AddSupplier').hide(); 
         $('[id$=AddSupplierButton]').click(function() { 
             if ($('#AddSupplier').is(':visible')) { 
                 //do this 
                 alert('event fired'); 
             } else { 
                 //do that 
                 $('#AddSupplier').show(); 
             } 

             return false; 
         }); 
     }); 

 </script> </head> <body> 
 <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
 <div id="wrapper"> 
 <asp:ImageButton ID="AddSupplierButton" runat="server" Height="18px"  
 ImageUrl="~/images/add.png" OnClientClick="return(false);"/> 
 </div> 
 <div id="AddSupplier"> 
     <select id="ddSupplierTypes"> 
     <option value="S">ss</option> 
     <option value="F">kk</option> 
     <option value="W">oo</option> 
     <option value="P">ii</option> 
     </select> 
 </div> 
 </form>     
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: My ASP.net is a bit rusty, is there a chance you could show how the HTML looks from the browser side?

Comment: Can you do a view source on he output, and see wht HTML you are getting

Answer (score 1):

It ought to work as far as I can see.

Can you test the following code in your document ready function

```
alert($('[id$=AddSupplierButton]').length);
```

How many objects are returned?

Comment: That selector is a weird way to find the button, so I agree that it smells funny (though it doesn't look *wrong* to me).

Comment: Yeah, the reason he's doing that is because of the lengthy ids that .NET assigns to elements. Pretty sure there's posts on how to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplify the above code but forgot to mention that im working with master pages. So on my Master Page i got this image button control

`<asp:ImageButton ID="AddVerskaffer" OnClientClick="return(false);"/>`

witch i call in jQuery as  `'[id$=AddSupplierButton]'`   because the master page changes the control name to some long ID.

Any now I replaced the asp image button with a normal link

```
<a id="AddVerskaffer" href="javascript:void(0);"  ></a>
```

and now it works. No event gets fired when clicking on the select box.

Why do you think this happens?